# how do i check input value that input value is in range of any interger or decmal from range -9 to 0 and up to 9 in this program?

Tags: powershell

how can I check the input value is in a range of any interger or decmal number from range -9 to 0 and up to 9 in this program?

My current code, which does not work, I'm unsure why this isn't working:  `$inputpecentw1.Text -match "[-9+9]"`

why this code sometimes do not enter value ?

```
$form_Load = {
        #выполняется при запуске
    Set-Location -Path $PSScriptRoot -PassThru
Push-Location $PSScriptRoot
         $file1.text="$PSScriptRoot\MIK_Autokontinent.xml"
}

    IF ($inputpecentw1.Text -match '^-?\d(?:\.\d+)?$')
    {
    $newpercent1 = $inputpecentw1.Text
     [xml](Get-Content $file1.text)  | ForEach-Object { $_.SelectNodes(' //FieldCostOptions/IncreaseCost') | ForEach-Object { $_.SetAttribute("Percent", $newpercent1) }; $_.Save("$PSScriptRoot\MIK_Autokontinent.xml") }       
    $inputpecentw1.Text = [xml](Get-Content $file1.text) | ForEach-Object { $_.SelectNodes(' //FieldCostOptions/IncreaseCost') | ForEach-Object { $_.GetAttribute("Percent") } } | Out-String
    }
    Else{ $value1=$inputpecentw1.Text 
    #[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($value1.ToString())
    $inputpecentw1.Text = [xml](Get-Content $file1.text) | ForEach-Object { $_.SelectNodes(' //FieldCostOptions/IncreaseCost') | ForEach-Object { $_.GetAttribute("Percent") } } | Out-String
    }
```

Comment: Try `$inputpecentw1.Text -match '^-?\d$'`

Comment: does not work '^-?\d$'       from 1 to 9 interger but i need decimal too and 0 and from 0 to -9

Comment: where do i read about '^-?\d$'  ?

Comment: By **never** accepting an answer on your questions and continuously adding more requirements in comments after the question has been answered, it is more than likely that people will not bother answering questions from you. Please take [the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and by doing so reveive the `Informed` badge.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match decimals too, you could use this:

```
$inputpecentw1.Text -match `^-?\d(?:\.\d+)?$`
```

Details:

> ```
> ^            Assert position at the beginning of the string
> -            Match the character “-” literally
>    ?         Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
> \d           Match a single digit 0..9
> (?:          Match the regular expression below
>    \.        Match the character “.” literally
>    \d        Match a single digit 0..9
>       +      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
> )?           Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
> $            Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
> ```

Comment: how do i limit value from -9 and zero including to 9 ?

Comment: @danrather This doesn't limit anything, it checks to see if the value given is within the range of -9 to 9 (inclusive) Did you try with various values?

Comment: i tryed with various values but sometime the program deny to enter value? why do i cannot enter value sometime.

Comment: @danrather For one thing, you do `[xml](Get-Content $file1.text)` 3 times where once would be enough. Next, your `SelectNodes` is wrong because you have a space character there which doesn't belong. Then.. there is no telling for us where the value for `$inputpecentw1.Text` comes from..

Comment: why $PSScriptRoot do not work if i use Win-PS2EXE.exe to convert .ps1 to exe ?   windows return error cannont find file C:\MIK_Autokontinent.xml but file \MIK_Autokontinent.xml is located in a folder

Comment: @danrather I'm sorry, but that has nothing to do with the current question..

Comment: Can we change $PSScriptRoot for another build in variable that work too?

Comment: @danrather You can use any variable you like as long as you put a valid path in there.